# How To Enter DateBox Data Into Database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, send, datebox

When a date is entered using datebox, it is sent to the php file as: date=2013-06-17
In the php, how should I enter this in a database easily so i can compare dates later?

Time is sent as time=14%3A24 (the same as 14:34 in 24-hour clock).
In php how can i enter the time into database? I was thinking about doing it by time after midnight, but how can i convert this (because there is a colon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Store it as a variable and enter it into the database.